# Strange printf() behavior

Tags: c, linux, sockets

The code I attached with this question is supposed to get the mac address of the device and print it. It works when I copy data from the struct ifreq to the array of uint8_t, but when I don't, I get strange results. Look at the second line, and second byte of the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint8_t tab[6];
    int i;
    struct ifreq one;
    int sd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, 0);

    memset(&one, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));

    strcpy(one.ifr_name, "eth0");

    int v = ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &one);    

    memcpy(tab, one.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, sizeof(uint8_t) * 6);
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        printf("%02x:", tab[i]);
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        printf("%02x:", one.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

OUTPUT:

74:86:7a:0a:2c:6d:

74:ffffff86:7a:0a:2c:6d:

Comment: What's your question? Why would you expect anything else? (The `printf` passes parameters through `...`, if you need type promotion to occur some specific way, you have to specify that. The compiler can't know by magic.)

Comment: printf("%02x:" ... can print 8 characters?

Comment: @Taiki Of course. What would you expect this code to do: `printf ("%02x", 5000);`? Or even `printf("%02x", -1);`.

Comment: @David Schwartz I'd have expected a truncated number...

Comment: I just don't know why the second result is differrent

Comment: @Taki Format width specifiers never truncate, just provide to fill empty digits.

Comment: @user2668536 Read what David says.

Comment: Okay so i just need to write: printf("%02x:",(unsigned char)one.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[i]);

Answer (score 4):

Are you asking why the 2nd byte prints as `ffffff86` instead of `86`?  It's because it's been sign-extended.  The `one.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[i]` array is declared as an array of signed chars, but your tab[] array is unsigned.

The args to printf are all promoted to int.  The unsigned character, 0x86 gets promoted to 0x00000086, but when the same value is assumed to be signed, it gets promoted to 0xFFFFFF86.

Answer (score 1):

Integer promotion strikes again!

As the conversion specifier `"x"` is used both lines `printf` an `unsigned int`.

To print the half of the half of an `signed` or `unsigend` `int` (assuming 32bit ints) use the [length modifer `"h"`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) twice:

```
printf("%02hhx:", one.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[i]);
```

Comment: +1 for "hh", but unclear why "0" is in the format.  Were you thinking `"%02hhx:"`?

Comment: @chux: my personal reception showed 02 ... - thanks for notifying!

Answer (score 0):

In one case, you specify how the promotion occurs. In the second case, you don't. You need the promotion to be unsigned. So not specifying how it occurs leads to problems.

If the byte is 0x8f, you need that value to be promoted as if the type was unsigned. Otherwise, preserving the value requires preserving the sign bit.

Promotion keeps the value the same. So it makes a huge difference how the raw bits are interpreted as a value when they're promoted.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, that one.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data is array of chars
An in this case char means signed char.

So, when passed through printf's variable argument list, it is promoted to int and printf prints it as unsigned int ("x" specifier)

When promoted from char to int, the compiler's goal is to preserve its value - not its binary representation.

0x86 is 134 as decimal, treated as unsigned char and -122, treated as signed char.

134 as unsigned int is represented as 0x68 
-122 as int is represented as 0xffffff86 (-1 as int is 0xffffffff)

therefore, 0xffffff86 is printed.
In such cases (printing binary as hex) I use %02hhx printf specifier
%hhx tells printf to treat it as an unsigned char - which has 1 byte only.