# API returning "incorrect" value for IP but if you add 256 or feed the negative numbers into an uchar it works. What's happening?

Tags: c++, c, printf, endianness, variadic-functions

Example: 
`printf("%d %d\n", ip[0],ip[1]);` will print -64, -88. If you add 256 and you get 192 168
`unsigned char a = -64; printf("%d", a);` will print 192. Any idea what's happening?

`ip[]` is a char array for what it's worth.

Comment: Simply make it an unsigned char array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange printf() behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694762/strange-printf-behavior)

Answer (score 4):

Plain `char` has implementation-defined signedness, **in your case `signed`**.

Because `printf`is a variadic function, default promotions apply, meaning your `char` is promoted to an `int`, conserving the value.

Unless you tell printf you passed an `unsigned char`, it will think it is an `int` or `unsigned int` and cannot reverse those promotions, meaning: 192 as char is -64 as int is -64 interpreted as unsigned is 4294967195.

The right format specifier would be `"%hhu"` for `unsigned char`.

BTW: The specific numbers assume `CHAR_BIT==8, sizeof(int)==4, 2s-complement representation`.

Comment: Thank you to you both, I now have the correct formatting and I checked Jon's wiki link on two's compliment and I get it now. :)

Comment: The third paragraph isn't right. The code `unsigned char a = -64;` initializes `a` to `192`. Then the default argument promotions take `(unsigned char)192` to `(int)192` and thus `192` is printed. This is actually well-defined in general, unless we were on a system without 8-bit chars.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Read more carefully. the start is not an `unsigned char` but a `char`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: yes, and obviously per implementation signed

Comment: I figured that your sentence "Unless you tell printf you passed an unsigned char" was referring to the code starting with "unsigned char". In any case, OP's code cannot produce 4294767232 on any platform with CHAR_BIT=8.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Nice you found a calculation error there in the end.

Comment: >< I am saying it is always 192, not 429-whatever.

Comment: The second line is always `192`, that is, and the first line is between `-128` and `127`. depending on values in `ip`